# Python httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port fail

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm trying to open a URL in Python that needs username and password.  My specific implementation looks like this:

```
http://char_user:char_pwd@casfcddb.example.com/......
```

I get the following error spit to the console:

```
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'char_pwd@casfcddb.example.com'
```

I'm using urllib2.urlopen, but the error is implying it doesn't understand the user credentials.  That it sees the ":" and expects a port number rather than the password and actual address.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use BasicAuthHandler for providing the password instead:

```
import urllib2

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, "http://casfcddb.xxx.com", "char_user", "char_pwd")
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen("http://casfcddb.xxx.com")
```

or using the requests library:

```
import requests
requests.get("http://casfcddb.xxx.com", auth=('char_user', 'char_pwd'))
```

Comment: Using the first code snippet gives me this error:
TypeError: expected BaseHandler instance, got <type 'instance'>

Comment: I"m still getting:  urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
Let me check with the guy who created the page to confirm he didn't screw something up on his end.

Comment: As a sanity check, I ran this on a known good page and the Python works just fine.  So this confirms that the current problem is with the access permissions of the new page... I'll talk to the designer.  Thanks for the help

Comment: the other side must implement the protocol correctly, otherwise it might not work, an easier way to make it work on your side is to set an header `Authorization:base64encodedstringhere' were base64encodedstring here is the string b64encode(username:password)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where I needed BasicAuth handling and only had urllib available (no urllib2 or requests). The answer from Uku mostly worked, but here are my mods:

```
import urllib.request
url = 'https://your/url.xxx'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
passman = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)
auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = resp.read()
```

Comment: I tried it but it response "'Request' object is not iterable"